# win_amd64.whl not supported on Windows10Pro-64

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyopengl, python-wheel

After a buggy Pyopengl pip-install on Python 3.7.4 ,tried installing the latest Pyopengl.whl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs#pyopengl).
However the latest version **PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl** gives the error below.It's been placed in the same directory that it is been run and pip is also on its latest version,
How to install win_amd64.whl on Windows10Pro-64 bit?

```
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7> Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption, OSArchitecture | FL
Caption        : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OSArchitecture : 64-bit

PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7> pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl  
ERROR: PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.  

PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7> pip install 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl'  
ERROR: PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

---

> EDIT1

---

Upgraded Python and pip to latest v3.8.2 
& v20.0.2 respectively but it gives an error.The whl is located in the main python path(C:...Program\Python 3.8) and is being run from their.
What's missing now?

> **ERROR: PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.*

```
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8> python -V
Python 3.8.2
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8> pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\user0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8> pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64,whl
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64,whl'
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8> pip install 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8\PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl'
ERROR: PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
PS C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8> pip install --find-links= 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8\PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl'
ERROR: PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: `cp38` means the wheel is for Python 3.8. Download a wheel for Python 3.7 or use Python 3.8.

Comment: Upgraded Python(v3.8) and pip but whl install gives error .Question has been updated.

Comment: `win_amd64` is a wheel for 64-bit Python. I suspect you installed 32-bit. Upgrade to 64-bit Python 3.8.